# push values to array with each in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

I want to push the options from a dropdown to the nested array "data".

```js
var gnames = { data: [], list: { sort: { enabled: true } } };
$("#dropdown-group option.lgroup").each(function(){
  gnames.data.push($(this).val());
});
$("#save-group").easyAutocomplete(gnames);
```

Why does it not work?

Comment: In what way is it not working?  What happens in your code?

Comment: post code on fiddle, that we can identify what the actually problem

Comment: @chandukomati better to recommend a snippet within SO than a fiddle as the fiddle site may go down in future.

Comment: You'll need to include (some of) the HTML for the `select` - are you sure each of your options has `class=lgroup` ?  Or does the `select` have that class and that's your problem?  We also don't know that your `select id=dropdown-group` (or the parent div could also have that id)

Comment: @freedomn-m there you go, I forgot to set lgroup class

Answer (score 1):

```js
var result = {
  data: []
};
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#select').find('option').each(function() {
    result.data.push($(this).val());
  })
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<button>Set</button>
```

My code can work.

Comment: "works for me" is a comment at best, it's not an answer. OP:"Why doesn't it work" A:"it does" OP:oh, ok then

Comment: My code worked if I didnt forget to set class lgroup :))